# Using POST in javascript with multiple headers

Tags: javascript, api, http-post

I amm trying to return API data i have key and username can anyone give me `Javascript` code to `console.log` the returned object.

https://developer-portal.driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/apis/vehicle-enquiry-service/vehicle-enquiry-service-description.html#introduction

```
    button.onclick = function(){
        var reg = document.getElementById("symb").value;
    document.getElementById("databox").innerHTML = " ";
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "url";
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("user","my name");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(json.email + ", " + json.password);
        }
   };
var data = JSON.stringify({"registrationNumber": "rf23mzv"});
xhr.send(data);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted specifies

> Every client is issued an API Key which is passed into the request as a mandatory named header as follows:
>
> ```js
> name: x-api-key
> value: {supplied API key}
> ```

Thus, you have to add this header to your request, and provide the API key that you have been given.

If you want to keep using XHR, add it like you add the `Content-Type` header:

```js
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", "put-your-api-key-here");
```

IMO this is much easier with the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead of the classic XHR.
It should let you replace all your snippet with something like this:

```js
fetch('https://driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicle-enquiry/v1/vehicles', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-api-key': 'put-your-api-key-here',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({registrationNumber: 'rf23mzv'}),
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(console.log)
```